# how to close a single window by mentioning filename opened in that window

Tags: buffers, vim-windows

I want to close a window by mentioning window name in command line.

For example, let's assume I have opened `1.c`, `2.c` and `3.c` in different windows in vim. Now i'm in `2.c` and i want to close `3.c`. Is there a way i can close it like e.g. `:close 3.c`?

Comment: what happens, if you have the same file opened in several windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:bdelete 3.c` or in short form `:bd 3.c`

There are a couple of terms you need to understand:

```
A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.
A window is a viewport on a buffer.
A tab page is a collection of windows.
```

So, what you're trying to do is close a buffer, not a window. The available commands to manipulate buffers are

- `:buffers` or `:ls` or `:files` : See the list of opened buffers
- `:badd`     : Add a file to the buffer list
- `:bdelete`  : Remove buffer from the buffer list
- `:bwipeout` : Like `:bdelete`, but really delete the buffer.
  And many more. You can find all about them from `:help windows.txt`

Comment: It's *possible* that the OP *does* know the difference between a buffer and a window, and really does want to close the window and not delete the buffer. I'm guessing that's not what they mean though, so +1.

Comment: If they *do* mean that, this is one way to do it: `:windo if bufname('%') == '3.c' | q | endif`